# How to get all non-formula and non-blank cells in VSTO Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Taking a look at this answer [Getting Cells with Formulas in Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507584/getting-cells-with-formulas-in-excel-file), there is an elegant solution to get all cells in an Excel worksheet which contain formulas. But what if I want all the cells that do NOT contain formulas? (I do not want blank cells either - I just want the plain cell with a value and that is not a formula).

Is there an elegant solution which does not include checking each and every cell in C# VSTO environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want the constants, which is sort of the opposite of the formulas.  There is a special cell type for this as well:

```
Range nonFormulas = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants);

foreach (Range r in nonFormulas)
{
    // Do some stuff
}
```

I think you know this already, but the formulas are just:

```
ws.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeFormulas);
```